# Generate json tree directly from SQL recursive CTE query

Tags: javascript, sql, json, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I know Postgres gives you the means to do this with `row_to_json` and `json_agg` (see [this article](http://bender.io/2013/09/22/returning-hierarchical-data-in-a-single-sql-query/)), but what if you're using a different db? Is there a generic solution for this?

Alternatively, is there a javascript library (orm or not) that provides a convenient way of handling this? I checked Knex and Sequelize, but they don't have it.

Comment: CTEs themselves are not generic solutions, depending on which version of a given server you're using.